# Add list of entity as parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api-odata

Is it possible to retrieve a list of entities as a parameter for an action in c# odata?

Tried the following but it casues the entire controller to not work:

```
[HttpPost]
[NhSessionManagement()]
[ODataRoute("BatchUpdate")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> BatchUpdate(List<Item> items, bool updateDefaultJSONFile)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

This is the config:

```
        {
            var action = builder.EntityType<Item>().Collection.Action("BatchUpdate");

            action.CollectionParameter<Item>("items");
            action.Parameter<bool>("updateDefaultJSONFile");
        }
```

This is how I then send the data:

```
$http.post(appConfig.serviceUrl + "api/items/Service.BatchUpdate", { items: itemsToUpdate, updateDefaultJSONFile: true}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    debug("Successfully saved");
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    debug("Failed to save");
});
```

In fiddler:

```
POST http://192.168.20.108/api/items/Service.BatchUpdate HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.20.108
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 83114
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://192.168.20.108
Authorization: Bearer ****
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://192.168.20.108/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7

{"items":[{"Key":"helpful","Text":"test"}],"updateDefaultJSONFile":false}
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify collection parameters as an array, not a list:

```
[HttpPost]
[NhSessionManagement()]
[ODataRoute("BatchUpdate")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> BatchUpdate(Item[] items, bool updateDefaultJSONFile)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Config is correct, good job.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now the controller seems to be working. But his action is not. I get a 404 error with these paramaters, without any parameters my call is working so its probably a missmatch with how I send and recieve the data.